# Move directories checked in a CheckedListBox to another. (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, directory, checkedlistbox

I'm developing some software that installs mods into the Cemu emulator. I've been having some trouble lately, mainly related to the CheckedListBox.

I've broken the code for it and it's not actually working as it should anymore so I've had to resort to coming here for help...

Basically, I just want to be able to check some items in the CheckedListBox (which are listed as folder names and not their full directories) and click Install Mods to just transfer them somewhere.

I don't really have any code to represent here so I'll just show an example of what I need. :P

[Image of representation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJWqg.png)

---------------------------------------------------- EDIT ----------------------------------------------------

Code:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\CemuModManager\Mods\botw\") And cb_Games.SelectedItem.ToString = "The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild" Then
        For Each Folder As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(tb_ModsDirectory.Text)
            clb_ModsList.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(Folder))
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This is basically all I have now for the CheckListBox. I'd be nice to know if it was possible to move checked items from their directory (listed above) to another.

FYI, the following are the names of the objects:

- cb_Games - ComboBox1
- tb_ModsDirectory - TextBox2
- clb_ModsList - CheckedListBox1

Hopefully the goal is a bit more clearer now.
Sorry about that. :/

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Unfortunately this question is too generic. Not to sound mean, but what are you expecting us to do?  Rewrite this for you from scratch?  I recommend you get to a specific problem and revise your question to include the code.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about that. I'll edit the post to include some code (mainly the code that links to the listbox).

Comment: Thanks and keep going.  It is possible.  Check out the available functions under `My.Computer.FileSystem... `

Comment: That's the only piece of code that relates to the CheckedListBox. Also, if it's possible, what event do I put it under to get the directories and copy from them?

Comment: This is your program, but my guess would be the Install Mods button's click event might be the place you want to do the work.